# Checking for null values in a table

Tags: plsql, isnull

I have a table with several columns some of them are:

- FILTER_COLUMN VARCHAR2
- L_FILTER_VALUEN NUMBER
- L_FILTER_VALUEA VARCHAR
- L_FILTER_LIST_ID NUMBER

I'm making a procedure to append a string (later to be used on a query)
but there is a catch:

If all of those 4 columns are empty, that's OK. However, if `FILTER_COLUMN` is not empty, I must guarantee that **at least one** of the other three is **NOT** empty.

Since I'm a bit of a nooblet in PL/SQL I've decided to do it "the wrong way":

```
IF FILTER_COLUMN IS NOT NULL
    IF L_FILTER_VALUEN IS NULL
        IF L_FILTER_VALUEA IS NULL
            IF L_FILTER_LIST_ID IS NULL 
                RETURN FALSE;
            ELSE 
                SQL_STMT := L_FILTER_LIST_ID 
            END IF;
        ELSE
   ....
 (and so on)
```

Is there a cleaner way to it and append all the not null columns?

Comment: Have you checked out [the `COALESCE()`function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, you have 2 basic options:

- Use AND:

  ```
  IF filter_column IS NOT NULL THEN
    IF l_filter_valuen IS NULL AND l_filter_valuea IS NULL AND l_filter_list_id IS NULL THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
    ELSE 
      sql_stmt := l_filter_list_id;
    END IF;
  ELSE
    ....
    (and so on)
  ```
- Use the COALESCE function which will return the first not null variable. If it returns NULL it means all of the variables are NULL:

  ```
  IF filter_column IS NOT NULL THEN
    IF COALESCE(l_filter_valuen, l_filter_valuea, l_filter_list_id) IS NULL THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
    ELSE 
      sql_stmt := l_filter_list_id;
    END IF;
  ELSE
    ....
    (and so on)
  ```